# Submenu Drop Down in Bootstrap not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add a submenu for the 3rd item in the list that is in a dropdown from the item in the navbar, I've tried using the classes built into bootstrap and was unsuccessful. This is in my navbar

```
 <li id="navTimesheet" class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Navbar Item Title<span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" >           
           <li><a href="path">item1</a></li>
           <li><a href="other path">item2</a></li>
           <li><a href="third path">item3</a></li>                                              
      </ul>
 </li>
```

**Edit:**

```
<li id="navTimesheet" class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Navbar Item Title<span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" >           
           <li><a href="path">item1</a></li>
           <li><a href="other path">item2</a></li>
           <li><a href="third path">item3</a></li>       

        <!-- from w3schools-->
           <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">New dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a></li>
                </ul>
           </li>

      </ul>
</li>
```

This link better shows what I want to do but haven't been able to.
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_dropdown_multilevel_css&stacked=h

Comment: Have you checked the console ? shown any error?

Comment: No I havent checked that. Let me put things back in and check

Comment: It shows no errors. Ill update the post with the code I tried adding

Comment: Which version of Bootstrap are you using?

Comment: my version is 3.3.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below snippet. 
As per your given link you need to change little html code and you have to add script to toggle dropdown.

You can also achieve this using css. see https://codepen.io/Magisters/pen/MwbeWv

```js
$('.dropdown-submenu a.test').on("click", function(e){
    $(this).next('ul').toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<li id="navTimesheet" class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Navbar Item Title<span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="path">item1</a></li>
        <li><a href="other path">item2</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a href="third path" class="test">item3<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: So basically the changes here are adding the scripts and link? Are they just for importing bootstrap?

Comment: @EnterStrandman yes it just adding bootstrap to your site. You can find details over here. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

Comment: I see now what it does. I guess I didn't explain well. So I'll update that, but in the navbar I have the menu dropdown but I want a submenu from one of the menu items like in this link https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_dropdown_multilevel_css&stacked=h